# Can't get Pretty Workflow Messages to work

Tags: joomla, message-templates, system-workflow-messages

I'm trying to use Pretty Workflow Messages to prettify system messages, in particular the subscription messages.

I'm running CiviCRM 5.36.1 with PWM 1.2. I've created a special message template and selected this in the PWM settings but the subscription system message is still as plain as could be.

I've tried with just selecting other templates too, but no difference.

Using Joomla and Swedish, if that might make any difference...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group subscription messages are not part of 'System Workflow Messages'. Hence it is not supported for them.

Here is the list of default CiviCRM 'System Workflow Messages'.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Right. Sorry, I confused them with Memberships. They're in Administer->CiviMail->Headings, ... I'm doing this to seldom... Too bad, though. Now I need to fiddle with message templates...